# Перенос дивов

Tags: jquery, html, css

Второй див оказывается под первым. Как сделать их на одной линии? скажем, делаю слайдер:

```
<style>
.content{
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.content div{
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
} </style><div class="content">
<div id="slide1">
</div>
<div id="slide2" style="margin-left: 400px">
</div></div>
```

(Изменяю margin на -400 и 0 соответственно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такое CSS-cвойство для div`ов( и не только для них ), как "float". Оно отвечает за обтекаемость контейнера содержимым снаружи. Пример:

```
<div class="content">
<div id="slide1" style="float:left">
</div>
<div id="slide2" style="margin-left: 400px; float:left">
</div></div>
```

Comment: про это свойство знаю, но результата нету.

Comment: Может это оттого, что суммарная длина двух div`ов больше ширины блока, в который они помещены? Сделайте это резиновым, укажите длину обоих дивов = 50% или 40%

Comment: да, в процентах заработало, спс